# CentOS7 と uWSGI で、Hello world

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

下記を試しても画面が白いままなのですが、どう修正したら良いでしょうか？
・Nginxエラーは何も書き込まれていませんでした

**Q1.HTTP/1.1 200が返ってきているみたいなのですが、なぜ画面に何も表示されないのでしょうか？**

**Q2.rebuild with pcre と表示されていますが、何か関係しているでしょうか？**

---

**Nginxのconfファイル**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    //中略

    location /hoge {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/app/app.sock;
    }
```

---

**hoge/hoge.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
uid = nginx
gid = nginx
socket = /var/run/uwsgi/app/app.sock
chmod-socket = 777
chdir = /var/www/中略/hoge/
callable = application
wsgi-file = /var/www/中略/hoge/hoge.py
```

---

**hoge/hoge.py**

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/html')])
    return "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><div>Hello</div></body></hetml>"
```

---

**hoge/で下記実行**

```
$ uwsgi --ini hoge.ini
```

・実行結果

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17 (64bit) ***
//中略
current working directory: /var/www/中略/hoge
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
chdir() to /var/www/中略/hoge/
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
//中略
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/run/uwsgi/app/app.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.6.4
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
//中略
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0xe8e200 pid: 27939 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 27939, cores: 1)
[pid: 27939|app: 0|req: 1/1] IPアドレス () {44 vars in 883 bytes} [日時] GET /hoge/hoge.py => generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (75 switches on core 0)
[pid: 27939|app: 0|req: 2/2] IPアドレス () {44 vars in 883 bytes} [日時] GET /hoge/hoge.py => generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (75 switches on core 0)
```

Comment: `hoge.py`でreturn文で指定しているHTML文中、`<html>`の閉じタグが`</hetml>`と記載されていますが、質問時の誤記でしょうか?

Comment: </html>の誤りでした！ 早速修正してみたのですが、結果は変わりませんでした。generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3ですよね? application関数の戻り値を文字列ではなくバイト列にしてください。

```
return b'<html><body>Hello, world</body></html>'
```

Comment: Hello, world 表示されました！ 「Python 3」の場合「uWSGI」はバイト文字列を返す仕様なのですね。return [b"Hello World"]のbは、HTMLのboldだから別になくても良い、と勘違いしていました