# CentOS7 におけるサービス経由でのuWSGI起動について

Tags: python, centos, nginx, uwsgi

**[リンク先内容](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43456/centos7-%E3%81%A8-uwsgi-%E3%81%A7-hello-world)で、uWSGIをCentOS7 のサービスから起動すると、「バイナリファイルを実行できません」と表示されます**
・ExecStartがおかしいと思うのですが、どう書き直せば良いでしょうか？

---

**/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service**
・sourceの後ろは、「which uwsgi」結果が「/usr/bin/uwsgi」だったので、それを書きました

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'source /usr/bin/uwsgi; uwsgi --ini /var/www/中略/hoge/hoge.ini'
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

**起動自体には成功**
・していると思うのですが…

> $ systemctl start uwsgi

---

**画面表示**

An error occurred.

---

> # systemctl status uwsgi.service

```
● uwsgi.service - uWSGI
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since 日付
 Main PID: 735 (bash)
   Status: "uWSGI is ready"
   CGroup: /system.slice/uwsgi.service
           ├─735 /bin/bash -c source /usr/bin/uwsgi; uwsgi --ini /var/www/中略/hoge/hoge.ini
           └─736 uwsgi --ini /var/www/中略/hoge/hoge.ini

systemd[1]: Starting uWSGI...
bash[735]: /bin/bash: 0 行: source: /usr/bin/uwsgi: バイナリファイルを実行できません
bash[735]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /var/www/中略/hoge/hoge.ini
systemd[1]: Started uWSGI.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source`コマンドは**テキスト**で記述された設定(ファイル)を読み取り、シェルに反映させるコマンドです。`/usr/bin/uwsgi`は実行ファイルでしょうから、このファイルに対して`source`することが誤りだと思います。

uWSGIのドキュメントにも記述例がありますが、実行ファイルをフルパスで指定し、引数に`ini`ファイルを渡しているだけのようです(`source`コマンドは使っていない)。

[Systemd — uWSGI 2.0 documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Systemd.html)

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/uwsgi/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
# Requires systemd version 211 or newer
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: 回答内容(sourceコマンド削除、実行ファイルをフルパス指定、引数にiniファイルを渡すだけ)に変更したら、無事画面表示されるようになりました！