# uWSGI Emperor について

Tags: python, centos, nginx, uwsgi

**[リンク先内容](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43466/centos7-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%93%E3%82%B9%E7%B5%8C%E7%94%B1%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AEuwsgi%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)で、uWSGIを複数起動して、異なる結果を表示させたいのですが**
・実行すると、画面には同じ結果が表示されます…

---

**ファイル構成**
/var/www/中略/emperor/
┗emperor.ini

/var/www/中略/hoge/
┣hoge.ini
┣hoge.py
┣hoge2.ini
┗hoge2.py

---

**/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --emperor /var/www/中略/emperor/emperor --uid nginx --gid nginx
RuntimeDirectory=/var/run/uwsgi/app
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

**/var/www/中略/emperor/emperor.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
emperor = /var/www/中略/hoge
uid = nginx
gid = nginx
```

---

**/var/www/中略/hoge/hoge2.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
uid = nginx
gid = nginx
socket = /var/run/uwsgi/app/app.sock
chmod-socket = 777
chdir = /var/www/中略/hoge/
callable = application2
wsgi-file = /var/www/中略/hoge/hoge2.py
```

---

**/var/www/中略/hoge/hoge2.py**

```
def application2(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/html')])
    return b'<html><body>Hello, world2</body></html>'
```

---

**実行すると**

```
# systemctl restart uwsgi

# systemctl restart nginx.service
```

・「hoge.py」「hoge2.py」へアクセスしても同じ結果「Hello, world」がWeb画面表示されます
・再起動した場合、両方共「Hello, world2」と表示されることもあります

```
# systemctl status uwsgi.service

● uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since 日付
 Main PID: 4706 (uwsgi)
   Status: "The Emperor is governing 1 vassals"
   CGroup: /system.slice/uwsgi.service
           ├─4706 /usr/bin/uwsgi --emperor /var/www/中略/emperor --uid nginx --gid nginx
           ├─4707 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini emperor.ini
           ├─4708 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini emperor.ini
           ├─4709 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini hoge.ini
           ├─4710 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini hoge2.ini
           ├─4711 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini hoge.ini
           ├─4712 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini hoge.ini
           ├─4713 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini hoge.ini
           ├─4714 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini hoge.ini
           └─4716 /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini hoge2.ini

 日付 uwsgi[4706]: *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
 日付 uwsgi[4706]: Python main interpreter initialized at 0xcec370
 日付 uwsgi[4706]: your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
 日付 uwsgi[4706]: *** Operational MODE: no-workers ***
 日付 uwsgi[4706]: spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 4707)
 日付 uwsgi[4706]: 日付 - [emperor] vassal emperor.ini has been spawned
 日付 uwsgi[4706]: 日付 - [emperor] vassal hoge.ini has been spawned
 日付 uwsgi[4706]: 日付 - [emperor] vassal hoge2.ini has been spawned
 日付 uwsgi[4706]: 日付 - [emperor] vassal hoge.ini is ready to accept requests
 日付 uwsgi[4706]: 日付 - [emperor] vassal hoge2.ini is ready to accept requests
```

---

**疑問点を追記しました**
・下記で、◯◯.sockのファイル名が複数ある場合(例えば、hoge.sock,hoge2.sock,)、location内で複数指定することは可能でしょうか？

**現在のNginxconfファイル**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    //中略

    location ~ \.py$ { {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/app/app.sock;
    }
```

**希望するNginxconfファイル**
・hoge.sockでも、hoge2.sockでも動的対応するようにしたい
・location段階で切り分けなければいけない？？
・それとも、下記の(.+)部分が間違っているでしょうか？

```
    location ~ \.py$ { {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/app/(.+).sock;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソケットが当たっているためです。ソケットは同じ名前にせず、例えば、hogex.iniを以下のよう修正にして、nginxの設定の方で、`/var/run/uwsgi/app/hoge1.sock` と `/var/run/uwsgi/app/hoge2.sock`を区別して設定してください。

```
[uwsgi]
uid = nginx
gid = nginx
socket = /var/run/uwsgi/app/%n.sock
以下略
```

hoge,hoge2サーバの内容が同じで負荷分散させたい場合は、nginxのload balancerの機能が使えます。公式マニュアルは以下にあります。
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

その場合は、以下のような記述になると思われます。

```
http {
    upstream myapp1 {
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/app/hoge.sock;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/app/hoge2.sock;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        location ~ \.py$ { {
            include uwsgi_params;
            proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答内容に変更したら、「/run/uwsgi/app」ディレクトリ内に「hoge.sock」「hoge2.sock」を確認出来ました。また、nginx設定について、疑問点を本文追記しました。location内で複数socket指定は可能でしょうか？

Comment: 上記のような記述で恐らく動くと思うのですが、ソケットでロードバランスの設定をしたことはないので、できれば結果を報告して欲しいと思います。

Comment: 最初に「conf.d」下のhoge.confに"http"ディレクティブを新規追加してみたのですが、「nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/hoge.conf」となりました。次に「nginx.conf」の"http"ディレクティブ内に追加してみたのですが、「nginx: [emerg] "uwsgi_pass" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf」と表示されました。iniファイルをたくさん作成していく予定なので本当は動的に設定したかったのですが、location時点で1件1件切り分けていくと期待した動作にはなるので、しばらくそれで試してみたいと思います